# Group R dataframe by counter variable and apply filtering/sorting

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**My dataframe:**

| amount | counter |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 1 |
| 778 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 322 | 3 |
| 51 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 17 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 489 | 7 |
| 224 | 8 |
| 33 | 9 |
| 56 | 9 |
| ... | ... |

**What I want to do:**

The counter variable is counting in which week my data is occuring.
I want to group the dataframe by 4 weeks, meaning I have to group by the counter variable e.g., 1 to 4, 5 to 8 and so on. Then I want to sort the groups ascending by amount and only keep the rows with the 30 highest amounts per group.

**What functions I might need:**

group_by (dplyr package) and filter (dplyr package)

**What I tried:**

I found out that I will need the "group_by" and "filter" functions from the dplyr package. I read thru the documentation and took a look at code examples but am not able to refer it to my usecase.

Comment: Do you want to group by four-weekly periods or months? Either is possible if you know the week number, but if you want it to be monthly you will need to provide the year as well.

Comment: Sorry that was a bit unclear, I want to group by four weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Four-weekly groupings

If you want to do this four-weekly using `dplyr`, you can do this:

```r
NUM_WEEKS  <- 4
TOP_N  <- 30

dat  |>
    mutate(
        four_week_group = cut(
            counter, breaks = seq(
                from = 0,
                to = max(counter) + NUM_WEEKS,
                by = NUM_WEEKS,
            )
        ),
        group_num  = as.integer(four_week_group)
    )  |>
    group_by(four_week_group)  |>
    arrange(four_week_group, desc(amount))  |>
    filter(row_number() <= TOP_N)  

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
# # Groups:   four_week_group [3]
#    amount counter four_week_group group_num
#     <int>   <int> <fct>               <int>
#  1    778       1 (0,4]                   1
#  2    322       3 (0,4]                   1
#  3    120       1 (0,4]                   1
#  4     51       4 (0,4]                   1
#  5      4       2 (0,4]                   1
#  6    489       7 (4,8]                   2
#  7    224       8 (4,8]                   2
#  8     17       6 (4,8]                   2
#  9      6       5 (4,8]                   2
# 10      1       6 (4,8]                   2
# 11     56       9 (8,12]                  3
# 12     33       9 (8,12]                  3
```

The output is the same as the input in this case (apart from the row group) as all groups have <30 rows.

#### Monthly groupings

You could do the same with monthly groupings as well if you provide a year:

```r
YEAR  <- 2022
dat  |>
    mutate(
        date_to_use = as.Date(
                paste(YEAR, counter, 1, sep="-"), 
            "%Y-%U-%u"), 
        month = format(date_to_use, "%B")
    )  
#    amount counter date_to_use    month
# 1     120       1  2022-01-03  January
# 2     778       1  2022-01-03  January
# 3       4       2  2022-01-10  January
# 4     322       3  2022-01-17  January
# 5      51       4  2022-01-24  January
# 6       6       5  2022-01-31  January
# 7      17       6  2022-02-07 February
# 8       1       6  2022-02-07 February
# <etc>
```

The rest of the steps would be the same (using `group_by(month)` of course).

#### Data

```r
dat  <- structure(list(amount = c(120L, 778L, 4L, 322L, 51L, 6L, 17L,
1L, 489L, 224L, 33L, 56L), counter = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))

# # A tibble: 12 x 3
# # Groups:   four_week_group [3]
#    amount counter four_week_group
#     <int>   <int> <fct>
#  1    778       1 (0,4]
#  2    489       7 (4,8]
#  3    322       3 (0,4]
#  4    224       8 (4,8]
#  5    120       1 (0,4]
#  6     56       9 (8,12]
#  7     51       4 (0,4]
#  8     33       9 (8,12]
#  9     17       6 (4,8]
# 10      6       5 (4,8]
# 11      4       2 (0,4]
# 12      1       6 (4,8]
```

Comment: I tried the Four-weekly groupings you suggested on my dataframe and it worked but not quite the way I intended. The whole dataframe is sorted by amount and not only within the 4-weekly-groups.

Comment: If the order is important you can change the `arrange()` to `arrange(four_week_group, desc(amount))` - I have updated the answer.

Comment: Is there a possibility to map the group to an integer in a new column?
(0,4)  -> 1 and (4,8)  -> 2 and (8,12) -> 3, ...

Comment: It's a factor so you can just convert it to an integer in the `mutate()` call with `group_num  = as.integer(four_week_group)`, - I have updated the response. Also  if you didn't care about having the labels at all you could just add the `labels = FALSE` argument to `cut()` - then group `(0,4]` would be called `1` etc. You can also use `dplyr::cur_group_id()` to do this kind of thing in other cases.